# Persistence Queue in java

Tags: java, jms

I have a use case in my project where I will receive a document and I have process it and send it to another module.
So I want to persist the received document and process it asynchronously.
We are not using any distributed application concept, complete deployment happens in the same system. So I feel using JMS is a little  heavy approach.
Just I am wondering is there any existing API which I can use it for this purpose?
I want something like light weight persistence Queue mechanism.

Thanks and Best Regards, Kitty

Comment: You could use Chronicle Queue which is more light weight. https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Queue

Answer (score 0):

As you want persistence, there must be "anything" to care about your datas.

API is just a door to some functionality.

Possibilities:

- serialize and store your "packets" in a file, for further reading by the other module. then, it's the filesystem who cares;
- use a database. it's the DBMS who cares; you need a DBMS;
- use JMS. It's not really complicated, and it's well established. It's the queue system who cares, and you need a server.
- other solutions will have a "server" which keep your datas.